# Developing apps for jailbroken iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, windows, ios, jailbreak

I know that you need a Mac and Xcode and the SDK. But is it possible to develop apps for jaibroken devices and/or regular devices using Windows/Linux platforms ?

### Edit

Also, what's the lowdown on the Airplay SDK ? Heard that it's pretty good but doesnt offer the same performance as an app developed through Xcode.
Found [this](http://pjtrix.com/iphone/articles/eclipse-cdt/os-eclipse-iphone-cdt-pdf.pdf) PDF Document, for what it's

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Short answer -- YES.

Although i'm not entirely sure what you mean by "ONLY" for jailbroken devices, but if you have any experience at all with flash scripts or action scripts then check out Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5. It's a program that lets you design and write your own apps for ipod/iphone/ipad.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html

I've used it for years and find it perfect.

Comment: Why use it when Flash Professional CS6 costs $100 more than the less powerful Mac mini or the same price as the more powerful Mac mini. Might as well just get the Mac and have it be easier. (Just hook it up to your TV and a spare keyboard/mouse and you're set.)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can, and that's what programming is all about. If you're a tough programmer you can do lots of cross platform and cross hardware stuff. Don't forget that no matter how cool Steeve Jobs is (or pretends to be) for Apple and maybe even non-Apple consumers they care about their profit and would never declare officially that building apps for iPhone and other iOS devices is possible on PC too. This way they make you get a Mac. They've been very successful in making people believe that building apps for iPhone is not possible otherwise.

Comment: But surely it's just easier, and significantly less hassle to just get a mac and download Xcode?

Comment: The point isn't to just give in and accept their dictated terms. It's about being able to whatever you want with your own computers, as long as you don't harm anyone else.

Comment: I myself have a Mac and I develop for iOs in Objective-C. I totally agree that it's easier than doing it other way. But no one can make me love Objective-C more than or even the same as C# or Java. What I mean is though I'd love to write in C# or Java I and I think most people find it easier in XCode.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a toolchain for Linux platforms](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/), but it doesn't have Interface Builder or other niceties. Here's [an example application](https://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/) that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for **theos**. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553722/768779).

Of course, you **will** have to have your toolchain installed, which shouldn't be *that hard*. There are a lot of projects which involve having a Linux iOS toolchain. Windows is another story, though :P (not saying it's impossible!).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no - fundamentally iPhone OS uses Cocoa, which is a closed framework only distributed with XCode. Some people have thought about reverse engineering (like Wine) but I don't think anybody has really been successful thus far, let alone use Cocoa as a development environment.

You might be able to create some debian packages (dpkg) that can be run in the background or via the mobile terminal. This is kind of limiting though, because you don't have access to GUI and your app won't be very intuitive.

There seems to be a development platform for porting Blender game logic into a full-fledged iphone game. Maybe you could avoid Xcode this way, but I doubt it.
http://sio2interactive.com/

You could run OSX within Virtualbox/VMWare Player but that's not allowed by Apple.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times I've heard someone say: That's not allowed by Apple

Answer (score -1):

Don't listen to other people who insist that you HAVE to get a Mac. You just need to download a copy of cracked VMWare with pre-installed Mac from http://thepiratebay.org/. You also need to download a copy of cracked VMWare player from the same site. Then download Xcode inside the Mac. No need to pay for anything. I've been using it and working great.

Comment: You can get the free version of VMWARE too.

Comment: I remember the name now: It's called VMWare Player

Comment: No, the standard VMWare player doesn't support Mac. VMWare has locked their software on Windows. You have to download the cracked version.

Comment: All the links on pirate bay are for VMWare images to be booted on MacOs. I can't find cracked VMware anywhere.

Comment: If any of you are looking for cracked or full version software, i know of a site that has pretty much everything you'll ever need. http://i4iphones.info  this site also has free movies, music, tv-shows, jailbreaking software, apple feature updates, and so much more. just sign up (it only takes like 2 seconds and its free) and go to the forums page at the top or just search for what you want. And no, there's no surveys which is my favourite feature :P  Enjoy!

Comment: i just checked and http://i4iphones.info has the latest version of VMware (both OS's)

Comment: Just use the free version of VirtualBox and you don't need VMWare, cracked, free or legally purchased.

Comment: Piracy is not the way to go. We can argue, but when you look at it, it is the equivalent of robbing a gas station. (And you probably steal as much money from the company.)