# How to create a basic MobileSubstrate tweak

Tags: iphone, cydia, cydia-substrate

I would like to know how to make a basic "Hello, World!" `MobileSubstrate` tweak.

Answer (score 2):

[Getting Started](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started#On_iOS) will help you setup the environment for developing. This [IPF](http://uv.howett.net/ipf.html) will help you understand building your tweak/app, and you can look at my [github](http://github.com/evilpenguin) for code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer in another thread which apparently was pretty much liked by some people; have a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553722/768779).

Still, @EvilPenguin's answer is entirely right, mine just explains a couple of things here and there, but it ends up redirecting you to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h> // for SBScreenFlash
%hook SBAwayLockBar
-(void)unlock // the method you’re hooking
{
 %orig;
[[%c(SBScreenFlash) sharedInstance] flash];
}
%end
```

If you unlock your Device using the Slider it'll screenshot your Screen. Its not a good Tweak, but it was all you asked for.

```
 #import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h> // for SBScreenFlash
    %hook SBAwayLockBar
    -(void)unlock // the method you’re hooking
    {
     %orig;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!" message:@"my first Tweak" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
    }
    %end
```

This will prompt an alertview to you saying hello world ;)
Have fun