# "Expected unqualified-id" error in Xcode and Theos?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, theos

Why am I get in this error in Xcode (and also when making package in Theos:
:Expected unqualified-id"
Here is the line of code I get the error for:

for(int i = 1; i<=11; i++){

Here's all the codel

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/PerPage.plist"];

for(int i = 1; i<=11; i++) {
NSString *str = [myDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page%d", i]];
if(str && ![str isEqualToString:@"none"]){
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Library/PerPageHTML/%@/Wallpaper.png", str]]){
        UIImageView *wallpaper = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320,0, 320, 568)];
        wallpaper.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Library/PerPageHTML/%@/Wallpaper.png", str]];
        [self addSubview:wallpaper];
    }
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Library/PerPageHTML/%@/Widget.html", str]]){
        UIWebDocumentView *docView = [[[UIWebDocumentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 320, 568)] autorelease];
        [docView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Library/PerPageHTML/%@/Widget.html", str]]]];
        [docView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [docView setDrawsBackground:NO];
        [self addSubview:docView];
    }
}
}
```

Here is the exact error from Theos (but it's the same in Xcode)

```
**Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm:5:1: error: expected unqualified-id
for(int i = 1; i<=11; i++) {**
```

Comment: That code is fine; show more.

Comment: Done, thanks. I'm trying to revive an old tweak to work in IOS7.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code (apart from the dodgy filepath of the `.plist` you load; but that's off-topic).

Comment: What's an `.xm` file?  What's "Theos"? (searches don't yield anything useful).  Provide a link.

Comment: Then I wonder why build fails with the above error!

Comment: Theos is for making Tweaks/Apps for Cydia (jailbroken iPhones): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118814/is-there-anywhere-where-i-could-start-mobilesubstrate-tweaks-programming/11553722#11553722